# Check if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe and create column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to compare values of columns in two different datasets and create a column with the results that have matched.

DF1:

```
 Dates
0   2021-10-01
1   2021-10-02
2   2021-10-03
3   2021-10-04
4   2021-10-05
5   2021-10-06
6   2021-10-07
```

DF2 =

```
StartDate    User
2021-10-04   Doe, John
2021-10-07   Ann, Mary
2021-10-07   Doe, John
```

Expected Result

DF1:

```
 Dates            User
0   2021-10-01
1   2021-10-02
2   2021-10-03
3   2021-10-04    Doe, John
4   2021-10-05
5   2021-10-06
6   2021-10-07    Ann, Mary; Doe, John
```

I can see the matches using the following code:

```
df1= df2.loc[df2['StartDate'].isin(df1['Dates']), 'User']
```

And i can return a 1/0 with the following:

```
df1= df1.assign(result=df1['Dates'].isin(df2['StartDate']).astype(int))
```

However, i cannot seem to merge them both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.join(df2.groupby('StartDate')['User'].apply('; '.join), how='left', on='Dates').fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Dates          User
0 2021-10-01              
1 2021-10-02              
2 2021-10-03              
3 2021-10-04         Test1
4 2021-10-05              
5 2021-10-06              
6 2021-10-07  Test2, Test1
```

Comment: Thank you i can get this to work. However, i have made a slight change to my dataset which now shows the Users as 'Lastname, Firstname' and when i use this code it only pulls the one user not the two?

Comment: Are you saying that each value of the `User` is a string in the format `'firstname, lastname'`?

Comment: correct. I have updated the question to show this

Comment: Check my latest update, @TiiTcHY.

Comment: It is still only pulling the one user instead of the multiple?

Comment: I'm confused. send me the output of `print(type(df2['User'][0]))` and `print(repr(df2['User'][0]))` (assuming all items in `Users` are of the same dtype).

Comment: it appears there was a whitespace in one of the columns that was affecting the search. I have now managed to fix this. Thank you for your help